# Prometheus 2.0 centos service won't start, because "Opening storage failed", "permission denied"

Tags: linux, service, permissions, prometheus, systemctl

**context**: I've added some scripts to an empty centos VM to install some monitoring tools including prometheus 2.0.

**problem**: Once installed in the non-root sudo user's home directory, I copy the prometheus.service that I wrote to "/etc/systemd/system", run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload, sudo systemctl enable prometheus.service, sudo systemctl start prometheus.service` but the service fails.

**note**: I can run the prometheus binary in the terminal directly using the same command without any problems, but I can't run it as a service.

Here's my .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=centos
ExecStart=/home/centos/prometheus/prometheus --config.file="/home/centos/prometheus/prometheus.yml" --storage.tsdb.path="/home/centos/prometheus/data"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's some of the log:

```
...
Nov 21 12:41:55 localhost.localdomain prometheus[1554]: level=info ts=2017-11-21T17:41:55.114757834Z caller=main.go:314 msg="Starting TSDB"
Nov 21 12:41:55 localhost.localdomain prometheus[1554]: level=error ts=2017-11-21T17:41:55.114819195Z caller=main.go:323 msg="Opening storage failed" err="mkdir \": permission denied"
Nov 21 12:41:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: prometheus.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 21 12:41:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Prometheus Server.
...
```

I'm new to linux services management, I've spent a lot of time reading online but I'm not sure how permissions works for services, and why it can't create the directory it needs to create.

I've tried:

- Changing "SELINUX=enforcing" to "SELINUX=permissive"
- Changing the permission to the prometheus directory to 777
- ...

Answer (score 2):

You also have to set up `--web.console.templates` and `--web.console.libraries`. You can copy these directories from exctracted archive. For example:

```
sudo cp -R ~/prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64/consoles /etc/prometheus
sudo cp -R ~/prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64/console_libraries /etc/prometheus
```

Example of working service (change path for yours):

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=prometheus
Group=prometheus
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus/ \
    --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \
    --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

P.S. Inspired by suggestions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-prometheus-on-ubuntu-16-04?comment=65680).

Answer (score 0):

Data directory for Prometheus should have write permissions for prometheus application user. If you're running it from a container and external mounting the data directory, you can set 777 permissions on original folder.

Answer (score 0):

If SELinux is stopping startup always consult journalctl -xe to view the SELinux alerts. There are recommended actions to be taken.

I have setup prometheus with SELinux on CentOS 8 without problems. And I don't agree with people that recommend disabling SELinux.

For reference Redhat has a good video for you to watch:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WOKRaM-HI4&t=1464s

Here is my prometheus.service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus Server
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=prometheus
#Restart=on-failure

#Change this line if you download the
#Prometheus on different path user
ExecStart=/home/prometheus/prometheus-2.22.0.linux-amd64/prometheus \
  --config.file=/home/prometheus/prometheus-2.22.0.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml \
  --storage.tsdb.path=/home/prometheus/prometheus-2.22.0.linux-amd64/data \
  --web.listen-address="0.0.0.0:9091"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```